# function php with parameter 0

Tags: php, function, parameters, int, switch-statement

I have a function like this

```
public function get_page($position) {

    switch ($position) {
        case "current":
            echo "current";
            return $this->current_page;
            break;
        case "first":
            echo "first";
            return $this->current_page >= 3 ? 1 : false;
            break;
        case "last":
            echo "last";
            return $this->current_page <= $this->total_pages() - 2 ? ceil($this->count / $this->nb_items_to_show) : false;
            break;
        case "previous":
            echo "previous";
            return $this->current_page - 1 >= 1 ? $this->current_page - 1 : false;
            break;
        case "next":
            echo "next";
            return $this->current_page + 1 <= $this->total_pages() ? $this->current_page + 1 : false;
            break;
        case is_int($position):
            echo "int";
            if ($position >= 1 && $position <= $this->total_pages()) {
                return $position;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            echo "default";
            return false;
            break;
    }
}
```

When I call the function, it works for every parameters except 0 and goes in "current" case in the switch.

```
$paginator->get_page(0);
```

If I call the function with quotes "0", it works.
But the function could be called like this

```
$paginator->get_page($paginator->get_page("current") - 2);
```

How can I call the function with parameter 0 ?

Comment: is `$paginator->get_page(0);` not equivalent to `$paginator->get_page('first');`?

Comment: i think some piece of code is missing ... the switch statement should go to default if input is 0 or "0"

Comment: how does parameter 0 go to "current"? shouldn't it be default? or possibly is_int()?

Comment: perhaps `switch` uses `==` instead of `===`

Comment: it's a pagination system. Based on the current page, I want to show "current page - 2". I call the function like this $paginator->get_page($paginator->get_page("current") - 2). When current page = 2, "current page - 2 = 0" can't exist and should return false (it should go in case is_int but goes in case "current" !!)

Comment: For the people confused by `"current" == 0` - please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_int` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`

`case is_int($position):` this is the same as `case -1:` and `case 1:` but not `case 0:`

In PHP, `TRUE` is considered **any non-zero value**

You're probably looking for `case intval($position):`

It's also worth noting that when comparing a `string` to `0`, it will always return `TRUE`, except where the string starts with a numeric, such as `23balloons`. This is how PHP works.

So you'll want **ALL of your integer conditions to proceed your string conditions** for the following reason:

> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value
>   and type are determined as follows.
>
> If the string does not contain any of the characters ‘.’, ‘e’, or ‘E’
>   and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by
>   PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other
>   cases it will be evaluated as a float.
>
> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.
>   Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an
>   optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a
>   decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an
>   ‘e’ or ‘E’ followed by one or more digits.

More information can be found [here](http://josephscott.org/archives/2012/03/why-php-strings-equal-zero/).

Comment: i'd might suggest a redesign to his pagination system... i think this switch syntax is buggy

Comment: The `switch` syntax is fine, it's the comparison of strings with 0 that is slightly misleading.

Comment: Confirmed. `case intval($position):` is the way to go.

Comment: For the moment, I have put this condition at the beginning of the function`if ($position === 0) {
            $position = "0";
        }`
which seems to solve the problem.
I will have a try with your suggestions today. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

change:

```
is_int // Find whether the type of a variable is integer
```

to:

```
is_numeric // Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string
```

Answer (score -2):

Add before switch:

```
if (!is_string($position)) {
goto default;
}
```